# Inline code inside a spoiler block is difficult to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

It is very difficult to read inline code when it is located inside of [a spoiler block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/205964):

**Readable (standard quote):**

> ActionScript already contains a `Math.pow()` function.

**Not readable (spoiler quote):**

> ActionScript already contains a `Math.pow()` function.

Comment: Should I include a proposed CSS fix for this as well?

Comment: Agreed. After clicking in the spoiler, I use to select its text for reading.

Comment: @Victor [**used to**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30035/i-use-to-or-i-used-to). I don't correct you to be a prick; I correct you because I care.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my main language, so I am likely to make a few grammar mistakes sometimes.

Comment: FWIW, this bug seems to be specific to the beta theme; it doesn't happen on SO, for example. Also, [looks like it's been reported before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-on-a-beta-site-is-evil).

Comment: @IQAndreas **It** is very difficult.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after being ignored with more than 70 votes for 2 years on MSO, I flagged [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/on-beta-sites-the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-is-evil) for moderator attention on Thursday.

On Saturday, it was fixed. Coincidence? Possibly. Either way, this is great!

Answer (score 16):

The problem is in line 1 of [all.css](http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css). (Admittedly, this information might be more helpful if the file had been created by someone with a functioning return key.)

More specifically, the problem is caused by this rule starting at character 31,193:

```
.spoiler:hover code{color:#222;background-color:#444;}
```

If the background colour could be changed to something a bit more sensible like `#ddd` then everything will be fine.

Comment: "(Admittedly, this information might be more helpful if the file had been created by someone with a functioning return key.)" I feel like using your enter key where it's not strictly necessary flies in the face of the spirit of this site. :)

Comment: Hey, [that's what i said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227391)!

Comment: @TheDoctor :-D Is your tardis on the fritz again?