# Spoiler code and text doesn't appear at the same time

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting, spoilers

Code and text don't appear at the same time.

> Second `First`

It's a bit odd, and Code Golf has a better reason to use code in spoiler text than any site on the SE network :)

---

EDIT: It appears this is not the first problem with spoiler text and code.

- [On beta sites, the monospace formatting in a spoiler quote is evil.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/on-beta-sites-the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-is-evil)
- [Inline code inside a spoiler block is difficult to read](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/809/inline-code-inside-a-spoiler-block-is-difficult-to-read)

That problem was fixed in April 2014.

I also found [spoiler transitions are strange here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/spoiler-transitions-are-strange-here?lq=1) which describes the same problem with transitions, though it was (incorrectly) closed as a duplicate of another question.

Comment: Nifty! Not that I have ever had any need to put code in a spoiler block. What's the use case?

Comment: @dmckee, I noticed it most recently in [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16573/17538) creative answer to "Write a piece of code that quits itself"

Comment: I've noticed it before but never really paid much attention to it as I assumed it was my computer & not the site.

Comment: It is true that this happens, but I don't think it affects its functionality that much, I mean, code appears faster than text, but so what?

Comment: @ace, so it looks bad. A bug, not a catastrophe. Only matters if you care about UI.

Comment: [Looks like this is fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/on-beta-sites-the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-is-evil).